# Variable taking garbage value inside a loop while calling a command line instance in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, konsole

```
do
{
    print"CHOOSE ANY OF THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS:\n";
    print"==========================================\n";
    print"1-LOGIN & LOGOUT\n";
    print"2-MAKE CALL\n";
    print"3-EXIT\n";
    print"==========================================\n";
    print("\nENTER YOUR OPTION: ");
    $option=<>;
    if($option==1)
    {
        print("IN THE LOGIN & LOGOUT SCENARIO\n");
        &Login_logout();
    }
    elsif($option==2)
    {
        print("IN THE MAKE CALL SCENARIO\n");
    }
    elsif($option==3)
    {
        print("\nEXITING...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        print"\nINSERT A VALID OPTION...!!!\n";
    }
}while(1);
```

Here the subroutine Login_logout() calls a SIPp instance(command line instance). After the successful completion of the command line instance the the scalar $option takes some garbage value and hits the else condition and prints the line "INSERT A VALID OPTION...!!!". This process continues infinetly until force closing the Konsole.

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong in the script.

Comment: $option takes some garbage value? What garbage value?

Comment: Don't know what it takes, I tried to print it out but nothing is displayed. May be when command line exits it returns some value and the $option takes it as $ARG[0] value. It may I m not sure.

Comment: I tried your code (removed the call to `Login_logout()`) and it works fine for me.  What does `Login_logout()` do? Can you update your post to include its source?

Comment: Login_logout actually calls a SIPp instance. The instance is 
"./sipp -sf Reg_UAS.xml -i my_host_ip -p 5060".For this you have to install SIPp in your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem that your external program call modify/redirects the STDIN, that way it is reads some garbage.

Set autoflush:

```
$|=1;
```

If you do not need the stdin/stderr on your external call, close explicitly it like this or redirects it to a file:

```
`sip.sh >&- 2>&- <&-`
```

or close just the stdin

```
`sih.sh <&-`
```

If I am correct this trick is works under recent ksh and bash only. At least under ksh :-)

regards,

Comment: @Shantanu: Shouldn't this be the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `<>` takes a line rather then a string, so removing return (CR/LF, etc.) is needed.

```
...
$option=<>;
chomp $option; ## chomp removes the tailing return
if($option eq '1')
...
```

Comment: While `chomp ($option = <>)` is usually a good idea, it isn't strictly necessary in this case.

Answer (score -1):

`do {
}while(1);` this is nothing but infinite loop only, no condition check so it will loop infinitely, more over try using `$option=<STDIN>;`

Comment: But still it should wait for the user input in the statement
$option=<>
then go for the if-else statement.
And also I had tried the $option=<STDIN> statement instead of simple $option=<>. But didn't worked out. Loop is running infinitely without waiting for user input.

Comment: try to put your code under `if($option =~ m/^\d+$/)` by which you accept only integers..i.e `$option=<STDIN>;if($option =~ m/^\d+$/)
{if($option==1) {print("IN THE LOGIN & LOGOUT SCENARIO\n");&Login_logout();}.....`

Comment: There is a condition check, if option==3 its makes an exit